# Acessing the click event for a customized control

Tags: c#

I made a customized control that is a picturebox and a button. When the user clicks on the button, i want to show a form that will capture the webcam image and put on the picturebox of the customized control. But i can access outside the control, the button click. I can access the control click but not only the button click...anyone can help me?

thanks!

Rafael

Comment: Post some code. What platform is this? WinForms? WPF?

Comment: Since he specified he is using a `PictureBox` there's quite a good change it's WinForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your control's constructor after the `InitializeComponent()` (if you have it), write

```
this.myButtonName.Click += (press Tab twice)
```

and the handler will automatically be created for you.